# Wrong ending single quote with \grq under XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, punctuation, libertine, german

I'm experiencing a glyph issue when using `\grq` from the `german` package under `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{german}

\begin{document}
\glq test\grq
\end{document}
```

`xelatex` outputs the wrong ending quote throwing a font warning:

[image]

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'OT1/LinLibertine(0)/m/n' undefined
>   (Font)              using 'OT1/cmr/m/n' instead
>   (Font)              for symbol 'grq' on input line 7.

However, it should rather look like this, and `pdflatex` does it right:

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `german` package that's obsolete and present only for compatibility with older documents.

However, the problem is present also with `babel`. I'll add the code for working around the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\glq}{\encodingdefault}{"201A}
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\grq}{\encodingdefault}{"2018}
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\glqq}{\encodingdefault}{"201E}
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\grqq}{\encodingdefault}{"201C}
\fi

\begin{document}

\glq test\grq

\glqq test\grqq

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, though, that you can input the characters directly, if you're using XeLaTeX:

```
‚test‘

„test“
```

The output would be the same.

Comment: Great, many thanks! Yes, I'm revisiting an older document that is stuffed with `\glq \grq`. In fact, I'm using `polyglossia` with `babelshorthands`, but unfortunately the single quotes are not (yet?) included. Does it mean that with your modifications I can do without the `german` package?

Comment: @Timm You *should* do without the `german` package.